# Python: How to switch off scanning of the lib directories at start

Tags: python

I have installed my own python with 10000 additional modules. Both the python and the modules are located on a small NFS share. When I start the python it scans all its library directories and looks for available modules. It takes several seconds.

How I can explicitly switch this scanning process off?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can start the Python interpreter with the `-S` flag. This means [`site.py`](http://docs.python.org/library/site.html) won't run and that won't scan for all the installed Python modules. The benefit is that Python will start faster, the downside is that many modules won't be included in your `sys.path` and you won't be able to import them.

Comment: Can I later add some modules that I need?

Comment: Yes just `import sys; sys.path.append("path"); import module`

Comment: Yes, you can indeed modify `sys.path` to fit your needs.

Comment: @JakobBowyer: Ok, I will try it; thank you Jakob, thank you Simeon!